# Demo wallet can't find .toml file

Tags: wallets, stellar.toml

[image]My stellar.toml file is currently available at https://wetheunion.com/.well-known/stellar.toml but when I test adding an asset that I am issuing via https://demo-wallet.stellar.org/  I get the following error message.

“ `wetheunion.com` is not a valid home domain, TOML file was not found “

I can’t figure out why the demo wallet is not finding my .toml file